# how to include only certain class to apply jackson fail_on_unknown_properties with false

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, lombok, swagger-2.0

how to  include only certain class from the package to apply the ignore unknown properties value with false.

the below class are generated from swagger2.0, in the below i want to include only farm.java and gym.java

```
com.person.test.model 
          house.java
          farm.java
          gym.java
          school.java 

my package:
build
 -- generated
     src
       main 
        com.person.test
        api
          testapi.java
        model 
          house.java
          farm.java
          gym.java
          school.java
```

i want to know the right property to set up in application yml or through the way to handle in Objectmapper config class to include only certain class?

```
jackson:
    default-property-inclusion: non_null
    deserialization:
      fail_on_unknown_properties: false





 @Primary
      @Bean
      public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder globalObjectMapperBuilder(Module... modules) {
        return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
            .indentOutput(true)
            .featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES)
            .modulesToInstall(modules)
            .serializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
      }
```